# particle systems - change direction of objects

Tags: animation, particles

I created an animation of a dress and added flying butterflies with the particle systems. Is there a way to change the direction of the flying butterflies?

Thank you for the help!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yC9jWIjqcIMtRPChT6jHtihgXYuQWbKJ?usp=sharing

Comment: how or in what direction should the butterflies fly? can you please maybe add a sketch or screenshot how it should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what direction you want them to go, but because you already have a boids system, you can do e.g. this:

[image]

I added a goal + separate with these settings:

[image]

and i added an empty, which is a parent of suzanne and i keyframed the rotation of the empty and i got this result:

[image]

so with a "goal" you can direct the particles in a specific direction.

[image]

Comment: Uuuu nice thank you, I will try it out! The only thing is that they look like they are flying with their back first instead of flying with the head first... I hope the explanation makes sense :D

Comment: you can easily solve that but selecting your butterfly, TAB -> edit mode, R Z 180, then it works. If my answer helped you please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thank you.

Comment: ou ok great thank you, I will try !

Comment: you are welcome